# Excel VBA: Copy / Paste Loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have searched extensively on this message board and have not found a workable answer to my issue. I am a beginner at VBA, but have done my diligence.

CONTEXT: I have a data block that updates from an external source (Bloomberg, not important for the question). I want to loop through an input (a company's ticker symbol) that drives the data update, and then paste the data block as a hardcode output.

UNIQUE WRINKLE: I do not want to overwrite the data for each update. I want it to paste *lower* down on my sheet.

ISSUE: My VBA code updates the inputs, but then pastes each updated data block in the same place on my sheet.

Here is my code. Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: I am still at an impasse with the paste functionality of the macro, but have successfully re-written it as an embedded subroutine to avoid other mentioned looping errors. I am only pasting the paste sub here to troubleshoot. Please see the ProcessData sub:

NEW MACRO (PARTIAL):

```
Sub CheckRequestingData()
    ' Check if data has refreshed, if not, continue to wait
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        If c.Value = "#N/A Requesting Data..." Then
            Call Wait
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c

    Call ProcessData

End Sub

Sub ProcessData()

    Selection.Copy
    Range("B100").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
                Selection.Font.Color = vbBlue
    x = x + 1

    Call LoopStart

End Sub
```

OLD MACRO:

```
Sub LoopMacro()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim dataRange As Range: Set dataRange = Range("B35:LA54")
Dim mySheet As Worksheet: Set mySheet = ActiveSheet

'Loop through company tickers, inserting into Company Ticker cell
For x = 8 To 21
mySheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = mySheet.Cells(x, 2).Value

    For y = 1 To 14
        'Copy live data block with active company's data
        dataRange.Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste each company's data separately
        Range("B" & 35 + 21 * y).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your intended behavior is :(. Can you show the data you have, and the data you want to have after? Maybe just 2-3 rows for each.

Comment: show some "before" and "after" scenarios of wanted behaviour

Comment: Your hearty address doesn't really inspire that much motivation.. Some pointers for your problem: 1) Anything with Selection in your code is bad practice and bound to go wrong at some point. It manually selects cells in your worksheet and manipulates them. If you change the selection during that process, the outcome is unpredictable. And 2) try using `Sheets("YourWorksheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, YourColumnNumber).End(xlUp).row` to compute the next paste position (only works if you don't have empty rows in between your data)

Comment: You should not have the copy/paste bit in a second, stacked loop. On every step of your x-loop you also do the y-loop --> you put another company in `C2` and copy/paste over all the ranges every time, overwriting what is already there. Step through the sub with the debugger and you will see that.

Comment: I'm not sure which part of the code you need help with - although I can see it's not going to paste at the beneath your existing data (there's no code to find the end of the data).  From what I can see - you transfer the values in rows 8 to 21 into cell C2.  You then copy B35:LA54 14 (inner loop) x13 (outer loop) =182 times and paste in to column B row 56 on the first time, 77 the second time.  As @BenDot says about the select - you could just use `dataRange.Copy` for example.

Comment: is ´dataRange´ on ´mySheet´ ?

Comment: '@RSinohara and @user: I will try to paste pictures / files. Not sure how to do this.
'@BenDot: Thanks for your helpful pointers. That's the stuff I need! On point #2, unfortunately I do have empty rows in the data block.
'@hsan: you have identified the issue prompting this post. Asking for a solution to it.
'@iDevelop: Yes, dataRange is on mySheet

Comment: @Darren: the code defining where to paste the data is "Range("B" & 35 + 21 * y).Select" . My understanding is this says row "35" + 21 rows * the matching number of loops into the sub. So 1st loop is row "56", the 2nd loop row to paste is "77", etc. Please advise on a better form to write this.

Comment: I'd use the method that @BenDot mentioned.  Create a new `long` variable called `lLastRow`.  Find the last row on the sheet and store it in `lLastRow`:  `lLastRow = mySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1`.  Change the two lines `dataRange Select : Selection Copy` to the single line `dataRange.Copy`.  Use a `With.. End With` block to paste: `With mySheet.Cells(lLastRow, 2) : .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues :  .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats : End With`  **NB:** Replace `:` with new lines in my example.